# SQL Split result into multiple columns

Tags: sql, datetime, split, sql-server-2012, pivot

I want to split the results from a table that has into several columns.
Each column is a Day of the month according to the results from the original query.

So consider the following table:

```
VALUE    |  TIMESTAMP
1        | 2014-10-01 00:00:00
22       | 2014-10-01 12:00:00
333      | 2014-10-02 00:00:00
2000     | 2014-10-02 12:00:00
55       | 2014-10-03 00:00:00
11       | 2014-10-03 12:00:00
```

I want to achieve a result in which, the first column is the time and each following column is a Day of the month (from 1 to 31)

So something like this:

```
Time      |  Day1  |  Day2  |  Day3  | ......
00:00:00  |    1   |   333  |  55    | ......
12:00:00  |    22  |  2000  |  11    | ......
```

I am able to achieve a single day, for example `Day1`:

```
Time      |  Day1  
00:00:00  |    1   
12:00:00  |    22
```

with

```
SELECT cast(TIMESTAMP as time) [time], VALUE as Day1
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE TIMESTAMP>='2014-10-01' and TIMESTAMP<='2014-10-02'
```

How do I get the rest of the Day columns?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Looks like sql server.

Comment: Sorry about that, SQL Server Express 11.0.2100

Comment: "sql server pivot query" is the google search string you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to use a dynamic pivot query.

In a non-dynamic query like this one you would need to provide a list of days in advance:

```
SELECT 
  [Time], [Day 1],[Day 2],[Day 3]
FROM (
  SELECT 
    VALUE,
    LEFT(CAST(TIMESTAMP AS TIME),5) [TIME], 
    CONCAT('Day ', DAY(TIMESTAMP)) D
  FROM TABLE1
) AS Source
PIVOT (SUM(Value) FOR D IN ([Day 1],[Day 2],[Day 3]) 
) AS Pivoted
```

But with a dynamic query you build up the list of days first and then inject it into a model query:

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols= ISNULL(@cols + ',','') + QUOTENAME(CONCAT('Day ', D))
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DAY(TIMESTAMP) D FROM Table1) AS Days

SET @sql =
  N'SELECT [Time], ' + @cols + '
    FROM (
     SELECT 
       VALUE,
       LEFT(CAST(TIMESTAMP AS TIME),5) [TIME], 
       CONCAT(''Day '', DAY(TIMESTAMP)) D
     FROM TABLE1
    ) AS Source
    PIVOT(SUM(Value)
          FOR D IN (' + @cols + ')) AS Pivoted'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Note that the query above doesn't make sure that the days are within the same year/month, and you should probably add a check for that, or limit the query to a given month/year.

Result:

```
Time  Day 1       Day 2       Day 3
----- ----------- ----------- -----------
00:00 1           333         55
12:00 22          2000        11
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2f4af/17)